# apache .htaccess rewrite - can I move this into httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

Below is the only code I have in the `.htaccess` file with apache 2.2.

I've read that its a performance impact to use a `.htacess` and better if this this can be run out of `httpd.conf`. Therefore is it possible for me to add this into `httpd.conf`? If so where would I put it?

Would it need to go into the VirtualHost for each Host that needed it (in my case a lot of hosts) or could it go generically into httpd.conf so it applies to all hosts?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`.htaccess` provides configuration for a directory, while httpd.conf provides an overall configuration. Of course, you can move content from `.htaccess` to `httpd.conf`.
You can find more about .htaccess here: [Apache HTTP Server Tutorial: .htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

Take your .htaccess for example:

Contents of .htaccess file in /www/htdocs/example

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Section from your httpd.conf file

```
<Directory /www/htdocs/example>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: yes, absolutely. quote from above website:   _You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance._

Comment: IMO previous comment should be included as part of the answer, as states something important related to the question and is something from official docs that has been included in other anwers.

Answer (score 2):

Each VirtualHost needs its own rewrite rules specified, unless:

1. You specify `RewriteOptions inherit` within each VirtualHost
   or
2. You use an `include` directive within each VirtualHost

SOURCE: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteEngine

> Note that rewrite configurations are not inherited by virtual hosts

Answer (score 2):

According to the Apache docs you may put the configuration in a .htaccess within a `<Directory>`-block. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

> You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.

To ease the administration I would put the rewrite directives in a separate file that is then included in each virtual host. It ought to work.