# Trying to include the contents of htaccess in httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache, xampp, httpd.conf

I'm trying to include .htaccess inside httpd.conf for better performance.

I am following the instructions from the readme file [here](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache) to improve site performance. I took the .htaccess and placed it in my website root folder `C:/xampp/htdocs/apps` then inside `httpd.conf` I've got the code below. then I restarted apache. The problem is i don't think the .htaccess rules are being applied

Is this the correct way of including .htaccess and am I including it in the correct directory?

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    Include C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\.htaccess

</Directory>
```

Comment: .htaccess and httpd.conf syntax is not quite identical, so ensure your include is using the proper syntax for httpd.conf, You probably should just put the "rules" in in the relevant <directory> section of httpd.conf rather than an include.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140605/apache-htacess-rewrite-can-i-move-this-into-httpd-conf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "include" the contents manually in directory context with the `Include` directive, set AllowOverride to none, otherwise you are applying the same configuration twice, once in directory and another through AllowOverride method.

If you just want to have a .htaccess file (wouldn't figure why because you seem to have access to the main configuration), then `AllowOverride all` would be enough.

If you just want to .htaccess and make sure it is being applied you can just:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and add junk text in the .htaccess file inside this directory, if it is being read, Apache will responde with a 500 error, if it is not, chances are you are landing in another virtualhost where this directory is not set.

Answer (score -1):

```
AllowOverride All
```

should already tell apache to let .htaccess override all settings. There is no need to include it manually i think.

Comment: Actually, it's just that so few of us have access to httpd.conf that doing it all via .htaccess is so common. Yes, there is sometimes a need to move directives out of .htaccess into httpd.conf since it will improve performance. .htaccess must be read and processed for every request, while the bulk of httpd.conf is already loaded into server RAM

Comment: Fair enough. But then AllowOverride All shouldn't also be there.